# Perl cgi script displayed as plain text instead of executing

Tags: apache-2.4, perl

After reading and trying suggestions from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792978/perl-apache-perl-script-displayed-as-plain-text) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561977/perl-cgi-scripts-ran-as-plain-text?noredirect=1&lq=1), I am still unable to get apache to execute the perl script.
I am on macOS High Sierra and running brew apache.

The script works fine if I execute from terminal using `perl myscript.cgi`. `myscript.cgi` is executable and starts with the `#!/usr/bin/perl` line. I double checked with `which perl` with regards to the location of perl. 
The problem is that it doesn't execute when hit from browser. The result is the script displayed in plain text.

My httpd.conf file:

```
Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf

Listen 80
Listen 443

User _www
Group _www

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

LoadModule proxy_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule ssl_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost:9000/"
</FilesMatch>

Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/vhosts/*.conf
```

In /original/httpd.conf, I uncommented the following:

```
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module> 
    LoadModule cgid_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgi_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
```

Within /usr/local/etc/httpd/vhosts/myhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName myhost.com

DocumentRoot /Users/pathTo/webroot/
<Directory /Users/pathTo/webroot/>
Require all granted
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/httpd/certs/wildcard.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/httpd/certs/wildcard.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why apache still won't execute the perl script?

Comment: Did you activate 'perl' access for apache? username@ANY-System /etc/apache2 ==> grep -n perl httpd.conf 170:LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so If you figure out how to get 'perl' to execute scripts, let me know.

Comment: Yup this was the solution to my problem. I asked around and someone told me to install mod_perl and try again. It worked :)

Comment: Now you've made me curious.  HOW did you "install mod-perl"?  Isn't it already on the Mac?

Comment: I followed https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/install-mod-perl-for-apache2/ and yeah some how I was missing mod-perl .so file. Install and activating it did the trick